Single prometheus notification description for multiple alerts
We have prometheus rule, that it will check CPU usage from different cluster. Assume these alerts are firing at same time. The description looks like The current cpu usage 90% in dev, The current cpu usage 90% in stage , The current cpu usage 90% in prod.
How to create description like The current cpu usage 90% in dev, stage, prod.
I have explored go template using join while ranging over alerts and other functions, but still no luck. Unable construct the description.

This is off-topic on SO
